# Imagemagick only reading red channel

Tags: imagemagick, tiff, imagemagick-convert, image-conversion, imagemagick-identify

I have a TIFF-Image, which i want to convert into a JPG. While on my local machine (Ubuntu 19.10LTS), I have ImageMagick 6.9 installed, the targeted system (Alpine 3.12.4) will have 7.0 installed.

I use this command to convert the image:

`convert 100U.TIF 100U.JPG`

While on my local machine the image comes out correct, on the targeted system only the red channel is converted.

**identify** on my local machine gives me this output on the image:

```
$ identify -verbose 100U.TIF                                                                    ⬡ 12.18.3 
Image: 100U.TIF
  Format: TIFF (Tagged Image File Format)
  Mime type: image/tiff
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 288x213+0+0
  Resolution: 75x75
  Print size: 3.84x2.84
  Units: PixelsPerInch
  Colorspace: sRGB
  Type: TrueColor
  Endianess: LSB
  Depth: 8-bit
  Channel depth:
    red: 8-bit
    green: 8-bit
    blue: 8-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Pixels: 61344
    Red:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 2.78762 (0.0109319)
      standard deviation: 23.7277 (0.0930497)
      kurtosis: 87.1252
      skewness: 9.22018
      entropy: 0.0306475
    Green:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 2.04869 (0.00803409)
      standard deviation: 21.3045 (0.0835469)
      kurtosis: 115.249
      skewness: 10.7066
      entropy: 0.0185803
    Blue:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 81.2182 (0.318503)
      standard deviation: 62.7872 (0.246224)
      kurtosis: -1.32139
      skewness: -0.234594
      entropy: 0.679964
  Image statistics:
    Overall:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 28.6848 (0.11249)
      standard deviation: 35.9398 (0.14094)
      kurtosis: 1.38693
      skewness: 1.63363
      entropy: 0.243064
  Rendering intent: Perceptual
  Gamma: 0.454545
  Chromaticity:
    red primary: (0.64,0.33)
    green primary: (0.3,0.6)
    blue primary: (0.15,0.06)
    white point: (0.3127,0.329)
  Background color: white
  Border color: srgb(223,223,223)
  Matte color: grey74
  Transparent color: black
  Interlace: None
  Intensity: Undefined
  Compose: Over
  Page geometry: 288x213+0+0
  Dispose: Undefined
  Iterations: 0
  Compression: LZW
  Orientation: TopLeft
  Properties:
    date:create: 2021-04-08T09:06:20+02:00
    date:modify: 2021-04-08T08:27:56+02:00
    tiff:alpha: unspecified
    tiff:endian: lsb
    tiff:photometric: RGB
    tiff:rows-per-strip: 4
  Artifacts:
    filename: 100U.TIF
    verbose: true
  Tainted: False
  Filesize: 65350B
  Number pixels: 61344
  Pixels per second: 6.1344MB
  User time: 0.010u
  Elapsed time: 0:01.009
  Version: ImageMagick 6.9.10-23 Q16 x86_64 20190101 https://imagemagick.org
```

whereas **identify** on the targeted system gives me this:

```
# magick identify -verbose 100U.TIF -set type TrueColor
Image:
  Filename: 100U.TIF
  Format: TIFF (Tagged Image File Format)
  Mime type: image/tiff
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 288x213+0+0
  Resolution: 75x75
  Print size: 3.84x2.84
  Units: PixelsPerInch
  Colorspace: sRGB
  Type: Palette
  Base type: TrueColor
  Endianness: LSB
  Depth: 8-bit
  Channel depth:
    Red: 8-bit
    Green: 1-bit
    Blue: 1-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Pixels: 61344
    Red:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 17.95 (0.0703921)
      median: 0 (0)
      standard deviation: 43.4868 (0.170536)
      kurtosis: 3.56005
      skewness: 2.22319
      entropy: 0.223782
    Green:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 0 (0)
      mean: 0 (0)
      median: 0 (0)
      standard deviation: 0 (0)
      kurtosis: -3
      skewness: 0
      entropy: 0
    Blue:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 0 (0)
      mean: 0 (0)
      median: 0 (0)
      standard deviation: 0 (0)
      kurtosis: -3
      skewness: 0
      entropy: 0
  Image statistics:
    Overall:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 5.98333 (0.023464)
      median: 0 (0)
      standard deviation: 14.4956 (0.0568454)
      kurtosis: 19.9054
      skewness: 4.51667
      entropy: 0.074594
  Colors: 238
  Histogram:[...]
  Rendering intent: Perceptual
  Gamma: 0.454545
  Chromaticity:
    red primary: (0.64,0.33)
    green primary: (0.3,0.6)
    blue primary: (0.15,0.06)
    white point: (0.3127,0.329)
  Matte color: grey74
  Background color: white
  Border color: srgb(223,223,223)
  Transparent color: none
  Interlace: None
  Intensity: Undefined
  Compose: Over
  Page geometry: 288x213+0+0
  Dispose: Undefined
  Iterations: 0
  Compression: LZW
  Orientation: TopLeft
  Convex hull: 263,2 278,2 287,4 287,167 276,192 255,193 171,193 29,156 8,47 80,13 113,6 161,4 263,2 
  Minimum bounding box: 287,2 287,193 8,193 8,2 
  Properties:
    date:create: 2021-04-08T07:06:20+00:00
    date:modify: 2021-04-08T06:27:56+00:00
    minimum-bounding-box:_p: 263,2
    minimum-bounding-box:_q: 278,2
    minimum-bounding-box:_v: 255,193
    minimum-bounding-box:angle: 0
    minimum-bounding-box:area: 53289
    minimum-bounding-box:height: 279
    minimum-bounding-box:unrotate: -0
    minimum-bounding-box:width: 191
    tiff:alpha: unspecified
    tiff:endian: lsb
    tiff:photometric: RGB
    tiff:rows-per-strip: 4
  Artifacts:
    verbose: true
  Tainted: False
  Filesize: 65350B
  Number pixels: 61344
  Pixels per second: 5.60942MP
  User time: 0.010u
  Elapsed time: 0:01.010
  Version: ImageMagick 7.0.10-48 Q16 x86_64 2020-12-12 https://imagemagick.org
```

I tried different values for parameters "-type", "-colorspace" and "-alpha", which always resulted in a red-only image.

Could it be, that I'm missing dependencies?

**EDIT:**
After i found out, i can reproduce this for all tiff files, i generated one myself and analyzed with debug-switch on (on the alpine-system).
The tiff-file, generated from https://www.freeimages.com/de/photo/butterfly-1390152 is located here: https://ibb.co/ZH1sgmK. The generated jpg-file here: https://ibb.co/1qYvkcs

```
# identify -debug all -verbose butterfly-1390152.tiff
2021-04-09T07:07:38+00:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.10 Configure identify[112]: utility.c/ExpandFilenames/971/Configure
  Command line: identify {-debug} {all} {-verbose} {butterfly-1390152.tiff}
2021-04-09T07:07:38+00:00 0:00.000 0.000u 7.0.10 Policy identify[112]: policy.c/IsRightsAuthorized/635/Policy
  Domain: Module; rights=Read; pattern="TIFF" ...
2021-04-09T07:07:38+00:00 0:00.001 0.000u 7.0.10 Module identify[112]: module.c/OpenModule/1273/Module
  Searching for module "TIFF" using filename "tiff.la"
2021-04-09T07:07:38+00:00 0:00.001 0.000u 7.0.10 Module identify[112]: module.c/GetMagickModulePath/546/Module
  Searching for coder module file "tiff.la" ...
2021-04-09T07:07:38+00:00 0:00.001 0.000u 7.0.10 Module identify[112]: module.c/OpenModule/1282/Module
  Opening module at path "/usr/lib/ImageMagick-7.0.10/modules-Q16HDRI/coders/tiff.la"
2021-04-09T07:07:38+00:00 0:00.001 0.000u 7.0.10 Module identify[112]: module.c/OpenModule/1309/Module
  Method "RegisterTIFFImage" in module "TIFF" at address 0x7f243e4edbc5
2021-04-09T07:07:38+00:00 0:00.001 0.000u 7.0.10 Module identify[112]: module.c/OpenModule/1323/Module
  Method "UnregisterTIFFImage" in module "TIFF" at address 0x7f243e4edf30
2021-04-09T07:07:38+00:00 0:00.001 0.000u 7.0.10 Policy identify[112]: policy.c/IsRightsAuthorized/635/Policy
  Domain: Path; rights=Read; pattern="butterfly-1390152.tiff" ...
2021-04-09T07:07:38+00:00 0:00.001 0.000u 7.0.10 Blob identify[112]: blob.c/OpenBlob/3430/Blob
    read 3 magic header bytes
2021-04-09T07:07:38+00:00 0:00.001 0.000u 7.0.10 Resource identify[112]: resource.c/AcquireMagickResource/390/Resource
  Map: 4.83943MiB/4.83943MiB/30.6038GiB
2021-04-09T07:07:38+00:00 0:00.001 0.000u 7.0.10 Resource identify[112]: resource.c/RelinquishMagickResource/1070/Resource
  Map: 4.83943MiB/0B/30.6038GiB
2021-04-09T07:07:38+00:00 0:00.001 0.000u 7.0.10 Cache identify[112]: cache.c/DestroyPixelCache/1057/Cache
  destroy 
2021-04-09T07:07:38+00:00 0:00.001 0.000u 7.0.10 Policy identify[112]: policy.c/IsRightsAuthorized/635/Policy
  Domain: Path; rights=Read; pattern="butterfly-1390152.tiff" ...
2021-04-09T07:07:38+00:00 0:00.001 0.000u 7.0.10 Blob identify[112]: blob.c/OpenBlob/3430/Blob
    read 3 magic header bytes
2021-04-09T07:07:38+00:00 0:00.002 0.000u 7.0.10 Cache identify[112]: cache.c/DestroyPixelCache/1057/Cache
  destroy 
2021-04-09T07:07:38+00:00 0:00.002 0.000u 7.0.10 Policy identify[112]: policy.c/IsRightsAuthorized/635/Policy
  Domain: Coder; rights=Read; pattern="TIFF" ...
2021-04-09T07:07:38+00:00 0:00.002 0.000u 7.0.10 Policy identify[112]: policy.c/IsRightsAuthorized/635/Policy
  Domain: Path; rights=Read; pattern="butterfly-1390152.tiff" ...
2021-04-09T07:07:38+00:00 0:00.002 0.000u 7.0.10 Blob identify[112]: blob.c/OpenBlob/3430/Blob
    read 3 magic header bytes
2021-04-09T07:07:38+00:00 0:00.002 0.000u 7.0.10 Resource identify[112]: resource.c/AcquireMagickResource/390/Resource
  Map: 4.83943MiB/4.83943MiB/30.6038GiB
2021-04-09T07:07:38+00:00 0:00.002 0.000u 7.0.10 Coder identify[112]: tiff.c/ReadTIFFImage/1520/Coder
  Geometry: 1600x1057
2021-04-09T07:07:38+00:00 0:00.002 0.000u 7.0.10 Coder identify[112]: tiff.c/ReadTIFFImage/1522/Coder
  Interlace: 1
2021-04-09T07:07:38+00:00 0:00.002 0.000u 7.0.10 Coder identify[112]: tiff.c/ReadTIFFImage/1524/Coder
  Bits per sample: 8
2021-04-09T07:07:38+00:00 0:00.002 0.000u 7.0.10 Coder identify[112]: tiff.c/ReadTIFFImage/1526/Coder
  Min sample value: 0
2021-04-09T07:07:38+00:00 0:00.002 0.000u 7.0.10 Coder identify[112]: tiff.c/ReadTIFFImage/1528/Coder
  Max sample value: 255
2021-04-09T07:07:38+00:00 0:00.002 0.000u 7.0.10 Coder identify[112]: tiff.c/ReadTIFFImage/1530/Coder
  Photometric interpretation: RGB
2021-04-09T07:07:38+00:00 0:00.002 0.000u 7.0.10 Coder identify[112]: tiff.c/ReadTIFFImage/1538/Coder
  Image depth: 8
2021-04-09T07:07:38+00:00 0:00.002 0.000u 7.0.10 Pixel identify[112]: pixel.c/SetPixelChannelMask/6294/Pixel
  butterfly-1390152.tiff[07ffffff]
2021-04-09T07:07:38+00:00 0:00.002 0.000u 7.0.10 Pixel identify[112]: pixel.c/LogPixelChannels/6178/Pixel
  butterfly-1390152.tiff[07ffffff]
2021-04-09T07:07:38+00:00 0:00.002 0.000u 7.0.10 Pixel identify[112]: pixel.c/LogPixelChannels/6275/Pixel
    0: red (update)
2021-04-09T07:07:38+00:00 0:00.002 0.000u 7.0.10 Pixel identify[112]: pixel.c/LogPixelChannels/6275/Pixel
    1: green (update)
2021-04-09T07:07:38+00:00 0:00.002 0.000u 7.0.10 Pixel identify[112]: pixel.c/LogPixelChannels/6275/Pixel
    2: blue (update)
2021-04-09T07:07:38+00:00 0:00.002 0.000u 7.0.10 Resource identify[112]: resource.c/AcquireMagickResource/390/Resource
  Area: 1691200B/0B/30.6038GiB
2021-04-09T07:07:38+00:00 0:00.002 0.000u 7.0.10 Resource identify[112]: resource.c/AcquireMagickResource/390/Resource
  Memory: 20294400B/20294400B/15.3019GiB
2021-04-09T07:07:38+00:00 0:00.002 0.000u 7.0.10 Cache identify[112]: cache.c/OpenPixelCache/3794/Cache
  open butterfly-1390152.tiff[0] (Heap Memory, 1600x1057x3 20294400B)
2021-04-09T07:07:38+00:00 0:00.016 0.010u 7.0.10 Resource identify[112]: resource.c/RelinquishMagickResource/1070/Resource
  Map: 4.83943MiB/0B/30.6038GiB
Image:
  Filename: butterfly-1390152.tiff
  Format: TIFF (Tagged Image File Format)
  Mime type: image/tiff
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 1600x1057+0+0
  Units: PixelsPerInch
  Colorspace: sRGB
  Type: Palette
  Base type: TrueColor
  Endianness: LSB
  Depth: 8-bit
  Channel depth:
    Red: 8-bit
    Green: 1-bit
    Blue: 1-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Pixels: 1691200
    Red:
      min: 135  (0.529412)
      max: 194 (0.760784)
      mean: 158.434 (0.621309)
      median: 144 (0.564706)
      standard deviation: 12.4204 (0.0487073)
      kurtosis: -0.118189
      skewness: 1.07827
      entropy: 0.852599
    Green:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 0 (0)
      mean: 0 (0)
      median: 0 (0)
      standard deviation: 0 (0)
      kurtosis: -3
      skewness: 0
      entropy: 0
    Blue:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 0 (0)
      mean: 0 (0)
      median: 0 (0)
      standard deviation: 0 (0)
      kurtosis: -3
      skewness: 0
      entropy: 0
  Image statistics:
    Overall:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 194 (0.760784)
      mean: 52.8113 (0.207103)
      median: 48 (0.188235)
      standard deviation: 4.14012 (0.0162358)
      kurtosis: -1.40876
      skewness: 0.737647
      entropy: 0.2842
  Colors: 60
  Histogram:
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.359 1.350u 7.0.10 Configure identify[112]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/675/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/usr/share/ImageMagick-7/colors.xml"
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.360 1.350u 7.0.10 Configure identify[112]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/675/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/usr/lib/ImageMagick-7.0.10//config-Q16HDRI/colors.xml"
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.360 1.350u 7.0.10 Configure identify[112]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/675/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/etc/ImageMagick-7/colors.xml"
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.360 1.350u 7.0.10 Configure identify[112]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/675/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/usr/share/doc/ImageMagick-7/colors.xml"
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.360 1.350u 7.0.10 Configure identify[112]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/675/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/root/.config/ImageMagick/colors.xml"
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.360 1.350u 7.0.10 Configure identify[112]: color.c/LoadColorCache/1983/Configure
  Loading color file "/etc/ImageMagick-7/colors.xml" ...
[histogram left out]
  Rendering intent: Perceptual
  Gamma: 0.454545
  Chromaticity:
    red primary: (0.64,0.33)
    green primary: (0.3,0.6)
    blue primary: (0.15,0.06)
    white point: (0.3127,0.329)
  Matte color: grey74
  Background color: white
  Border color: srgb(223,223,223)
  Transparent color: none
  Interlace: None
  Intensity: Undefined
  Compose: Over
  Page geometry: 1600x1057+0+0
  Dispose: Undefined
  Iterations: 0
  Compression: None
  Orientation: TopLeft
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.362 1.350u 7.0.10 Pixel identify[112]: pixel.c/SetPixelChannelMask/6294/Pixel
  butterfly-1390152.tiff[07ffffff]
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.362 1.350u 7.0.10 Pixel identify[112]: pixel.c/LogPixelChannels/6178/Pixel
  butterfly-1390152.tiff[07ffffff]
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.362 1.350u 7.0.10 Pixel identify[112]: pixel.c/LogPixelChannels/6275/Pixel
    0: red (update)
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.362 1.350u 7.0.10 Pixel identify[112]: pixel.c/LogPixelChannels/6275/Pixel
    1: green (update)
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.362 1.350u 7.0.10 Pixel identify[112]: pixel.c/LogPixelChannels/6275/Pixel
    2: blue (update)
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.362 1.350u 7.0.10 Resource identify[112]: resource.c/AcquireMagickResource/390/Resource
  Area: 1600B/0B/30.6038GiB
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.362 1.350u 7.0.10 Resource identify[112]: resource.c/AcquireMagickResource/390/Resource
  Memory: 19200B/20313600B/15.3019GiB
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.362 1.350u 7.0.10 Cache identify[112]: cache.c/OpenPixelCache/3794/Cache
  open butterfly-1390152.tiff[0] (Heap Memory, 1600x1x3 19200B)
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.362 1.350u 7.0.10 Cache identify[112]: cache.c/DestroyPixelCache/1057/Cache
  destroy butterfly-1390152.tiff[0]
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.362 1.350u 7.0.10 Resource identify[112]: resource.c/RelinquishMagickResource/1070/Resource
  Memory: 19200B/20294400B/15.3019GiB
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.362 1.350u 7.0.10 Pixel identify[112]: pixel.c/SetPixelChannelMask/6294/Pixel
  butterfly-1390152.tiff[07ffffff]
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.362 1.350u 7.0.10 Pixel identify[112]: pixel.c/LogPixelChannels/6178/Pixel
  butterfly-1390152.tiff[07ffffff]
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.362 1.350u 7.0.10 Pixel identify[112]: pixel.c/LogPixelChannels/6275/Pixel
    0: red (update)
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.362 1.350u 7.0.10 Pixel identify[112]: pixel.c/LogPixelChannels/6275/Pixel
    1: green (update)
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.362 1.350u 7.0.10 Pixel identify[112]: pixel.c/LogPixelChannels/6275/Pixel
    2: blue (update)
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.362 1.350u 7.0.10 Resource identify[112]: resource.c/AcquireMagickResource/390/Resource
  Area: 1600B/0B/30.6038GiB
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.362 1.350u 7.0.10 Resource identify[112]: resource.c/AcquireMagickResource/390/Resource
  Memory: 19200B/20313600B/15.3019GiB
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.362 1.350u 7.0.10 Cache identify[112]: cache.c/OpenPixelCache/3794/Cache
  open butterfly-1390152.tiff[0] (Heap Memory, 1600x1x3 19200B)
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.362 1.350u 7.0.10 Cache identify[112]: cache.c/DestroyPixelCache/1057/Cache
  destroy butterfly-1390152.tiff[0]
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.362 1.350u 7.0.10 Resource identify[112]: resource.c/RelinquishMagickResource/1070/Resource
  Memory: 19200B/20294400B/15.3019GiB
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.362 1.350u 7.0.10 Pixel identify[112]: pixel.c/SetPixelChannelMask/6294/Pixel
  butterfly-1390152.tiff[07ffffff]
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.362 1.350u 7.0.10 Pixel identify[112]: pixel.c/LogPixelChannels/6178/Pixel
  butterfly-1390152.tiff[07ffffff]
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.362 1.350u 7.0.10 Pixel identify[112]: pixel.c/LogPixelChannels/6275/Pixel
    0: red (update)
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.362 1.350u 7.0.10 Pixel identify[112]: pixel.c/LogPixelChannels/6275/Pixel
    1: green (update)
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.362 1.350u 7.0.10 Pixel identify[112]: pixel.c/LogPixelChannels/6275/Pixel
    2: blue (update)
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.362 1.350u 7.0.10 Resource identify[112]: resource.c/AcquireMagickResource/390/Resource
  Area: 1600B/0B/30.6038GiB
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.362 1.350u 7.0.10 Resource identify[112]: resource.c/AcquireMagickResource/390/Resource
  Memory: 19200B/20313600B/15.3019GiB
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.362 1.350u 7.0.10 Cache identify[112]: cache.c/OpenPixelCache/3794/Cache
  open butterfly-1390152.tiff[0] (Heap Memory, 1600x1x3 19200B)
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.362 1.350u 7.0.10 Cache identify[112]: cache.c/DestroyPixelCache/1057/Cache
  destroy butterfly-1390152.tiff[0]
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.362 1.350u 7.0.10 Resource identify[112]: resource.c/RelinquishMagickResource/1070/Resource
  Memory: 19200B/20294400B/15.3019GiB
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.362 1.350u 7.0.10 Pixel identify[112]: pixel.c/SetPixelChannelMask/6294/Pixel
  butterfly-1390152.tiff[07ffffff]
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.362 1.350u 7.0.10 Pixel identify[112]: pixel.c/LogPixelChannels/6178/Pixel
  butterfly-1390152.tiff[07ffffff]
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.363 1.350u 7.0.10 Pixel identify[112]: pixel.c/LogPixelChannels/6275/Pixel
    0: red (update)
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.363 1.350u 7.0.10 Pixel identify[112]: pixel.c/LogPixelChannels/6275/Pixel
    1: green (update)
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.363 1.350u 7.0.10 Pixel identify[112]: pixel.c/LogPixelChannels/6275/Pixel
    2: blue (update)
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.363 1.350u 7.0.10 Resource identify[112]: resource.c/AcquireMagickResource/390/Resource
  Area: 1600B/0B/30.6038GiB
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.363 1.350u 7.0.10 Resource identify[112]: resource.c/AcquireMagickResource/390/Resource
  Memory: 19200B/20313600B/15.3019GiB
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.363 1.350u 7.0.10 Cache identify[112]: cache.c/OpenPixelCache/3794/Cache
  open butterfly-1390152.tiff[0] (Heap Memory, 1600x1x3 19200B)
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.363 1.350u 7.0.10 Cache identify[112]: cache.c/DestroyPixelCache/1057/Cache
  destroy butterfly-1390152.tiff[0]
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.363 1.350u 7.0.10 Resource identify[112]: resource.c/RelinquishMagickResource/1070/Resource
  Memory: 19200B/20294400B/15.3019GiB
  Convex hull: 0,0 1599,0 1599,1055 1598,1056 0,1056 0,0 
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.412 1.400u 7.0.10 Pixel identify[112]: pixel.c/SetPixelChannelMask/6294/Pixel
  butterfly-1390152.tiff[07ffffff]
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.412 1.400u 7.0.10 Pixel identify[112]: pixel.c/LogPixelChannels/6178/Pixel
  butterfly-1390152.tiff[07ffffff]
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.412 1.400u 7.0.10 Pixel identify[112]: pixel.c/LogPixelChannels/6275/Pixel
    0: red (update)
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.412 1.400u 7.0.10 Pixel identify[112]: pixel.c/LogPixelChannels/6275/Pixel
    1: green (update)
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.412 1.400u 7.0.10 Pixel identify[112]: pixel.c/LogPixelChannels/6275/Pixel
    2: blue (update)
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.412 1.400u 7.0.10 Resource identify[112]: resource.c/AcquireMagickResource/390/Resource
  Area: 1600B/0B/30.6038GiB
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.412 1.400u 7.0.10 Resource identify[112]: resource.c/AcquireMagickResource/390/Resource
  Memory: 19200B/20313600B/15.3019GiB
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.413 1.400u 7.0.10 Cache identify[112]: cache.c/OpenPixelCache/3794/Cache
  open butterfly-1390152.tiff[0] (Heap Memory, 1600x1x3 19200B)
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.413 1.400u 7.0.10 Cache identify[112]: cache.c/DestroyPixelCache/1057/Cache
  destroy butterfly-1390152.tiff[0]
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.413 1.400u 7.0.10 Resource identify[112]: resource.c/RelinquishMagickResource/1070/Resource
  Memory: 19200B/20294400B/15.3019GiB
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.413 1.400u 7.0.10 Pixel identify[112]: pixel.c/SetPixelChannelMask/6294/Pixel
  butterfly-1390152.tiff[07ffffff]
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.413 1.400u 7.0.10 Pixel identify[112]: pixel.c/LogPixelChannels/6178/Pixel
  butterfly-1390152.tiff[07ffffff]
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.413 1.400u 7.0.10 Pixel identify[112]: pixel.c/LogPixelChannels/6275/Pixel
    0: red (update)
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.413 1.400u 7.0.10 Pixel identify[112]: pixel.c/LogPixelChannels/6275/Pixel
    1: green (update)
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.413 1.400u 7.0.10 Pixel identify[112]: pixel.c/LogPixelChannels/6275/Pixel
    2: blue (update)
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.413 1.400u 7.0.10 Resource identify[112]: resource.c/AcquireMagickResource/390/Resource
  Area: 1600B/0B/30.6038GiB
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.413 1.400u 7.0.10 Resource identify[112]: resource.c/AcquireMagickResource/390/Resource
  Memory: 19200B/20313600B/15.3019GiB
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.413 1.400u 7.0.10 Cache identify[112]: cache.c/OpenPixelCache/3794/Cache
  open butterfly-1390152.tiff[0] (Heap Memory, 1600x1x3 19200B)
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.413 1.400u 7.0.10 Cache identify[112]: cache.c/DestroyPixelCache/1057/Cache
  destroy butterfly-1390152.tiff[0]
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.413 1.400u 7.0.10 Resource identify[112]: resource.c/RelinquishMagickResource/1070/Resource
  Memory: 19200B/20294400B/15.3019GiB
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.413 1.400u 7.0.10 Pixel identify[112]: pixel.c/SetPixelChannelMask/6294/Pixel
  butterfly-1390152.tiff[07ffffff]
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.413 1.400u 7.0.10 Pixel identify[112]: pixel.c/LogPixelChannels/6178/Pixel
  butterfly-1390152.tiff[07ffffff]
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.413 1.400u 7.0.10 Pixel identify[112]: pixel.c/LogPixelChannels/6275/Pixel
    0: red (update)
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.413 1.400u 7.0.10 Pixel identify[112]: pixel.c/LogPixelChannels/6275/Pixel
    1: green (update)
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.413 1.400u 7.0.10 Pixel identify[112]: pixel.c/LogPixelChannels/6275/Pixel
    2: blue (update)
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.413 1.400u 7.0.10 Resource identify[112]: resource.c/AcquireMagickResource/390/Resource
  Area: 1600B/0B/30.6038GiB
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.413 1.400u 7.0.10 Resource identify[112]: resource.c/AcquireMagickResource/390/Resource
  Memory: 19200B/20313600B/15.3019GiB
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.413 1.400u 7.0.10 Cache identify[112]: cache.c/OpenPixelCache/3794/Cache
  open butterfly-1390152.tiff[0] (Heap Memory, 1600x1x3 19200B)
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.413 1.400u 7.0.10 Cache identify[112]: cache.c/DestroyPixelCache/1057/Cache
  destroy butterfly-1390152.tiff[0]
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.413 1.400u 7.0.10 Resource identify[112]: resource.c/RelinquishMagickResource/1070/Resource
  Memory: 19200B/20294400B/15.3019GiB
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.413 1.400u 7.0.10 Pixel identify[112]: pixel.c/SetPixelChannelMask/6294/Pixel
  butterfly-1390152.tiff[07ffffff]
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.413 1.400u 7.0.10 Pixel identify[112]: pixel.c/LogPixelChannels/6178/Pixel
  butterfly-1390152.tiff[07ffffff]
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.413 1.400u 7.0.10 Pixel identify[112]: pixel.c/LogPixelChannels/6275/Pixel
    0: red (update)
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.413 1.400u 7.0.10 Pixel identify[112]: pixel.c/LogPixelChannels/6275/Pixel
    1: green (update)
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.413 1.400u 7.0.10 Pixel identify[112]: pixel.c/LogPixelChannels/6275/Pixel
    2: blue (update)
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.413 1.400u 7.0.10 Resource identify[112]: resource.c/AcquireMagickResource/390/Resource
  Area: 1600B/0B/30.6038GiB
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.413 1.400u 7.0.10 Resource identify[112]: resource.c/AcquireMagickResource/390/Resource
  Memory: 19200B/20313600B/15.3019GiB
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.413 1.400u 7.0.10 Cache identify[112]: cache.c/OpenPixelCache/3794/Cache
  open butterfly-1390152.tiff[0] (Heap Memory, 1600x1x3 19200B)
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.413 1.400u 7.0.10 Cache identify[112]: cache.c/DestroyPixelCache/1057/Cache
  destroy butterfly-1390152.tiff[0]
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.414 1.400u 7.0.10 Resource identify[112]: resource.c/RelinquishMagickResource/1070/Resource
  Memory: 19200B/20294400B/15.3019GiB
  Minimum bounding box: 1599,0 1599,1056 0,1056 0,0 
  Profiles:
    Profile-8bim: 12 bytes
8bim(12):
0x00000000: 42494d04 04000000 00000000                    8BIM--------
    Profile-icc: 560 bytes
icc(560):
0x00000000: 00023041 44424502 1000006d 6e747252 47422058  ---0ADBE----mntrRGB 
0x00000190: 595a2007 d0000800 0b001300 33003b61 63737041  XYZ ---------3-;acsp
0x00000320: 50504c00 0000006e 6f6e6500 00000000 00000000  APPL----none--------
0x000004b0: 00000000 00000100 00f6d600 01000000 00d32d41  --------------------
0x00000640: 44424500 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ADBE----------------
0x000007d0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  --------------------
0x00000960: 00000000 00000000 00000a63 70727400 0000fc00  ------------cprt----
0x00000af0: 00003264 65736300 00013000 00006b77 74707400  ---2desc---0---kwtpt
0x00000c80: 00019c00 00001462 6b707400 0001b000 00001472  --------bkpt--------
0x00000e10: 54524300 0001c400 00000e67 54524300 0001d400  rTRC--------gTRC----
0x00000fa0: 00000e62 54524300 0001e400 00000e72 58595a00  ----bTRC--------rXYZ
0x00001130: 0001f400 00001467 58595a00 00020800 00001462  --------gXYZ--------
0x000012c0: 58595a00 00021c00 00001474 65787400 00000043  bXYZ--------text----
0x00001450: 6f707972 69676874 20323030 30204164 6f626520  Copyright 2000 Adobe
0x000015e0: 53797374 656d7320 496e636f 72706f72 61746564   Systems Incorporate
0x00001770: 00000064 65736300 00000000 00001141 646f6265  d---desc--------Adob
0x00001900: 20524742 20283139 39382900 00000000 00000000  e RGB (1998)--------
0x00001a90: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  --------------------
0x00001c20: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  --------------------
0x00001db0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  --------------------
0x00001f40: 00000000 00000000 00000058 595a2000 00000000  ------------XYZ ----
0x000020d0: 00f35100 01000000 0116cc58 595a2000 00000000  ---Q--------XYZ ----
0x00002260: 00000000 00000000 00000063 75727600 00000000  ------------curv----
0x000023f0: 00000102 33000063 75727600 00000000 00000102  -----3--curv--------
0x00002580: 33000063 75727600 00000000 00000102 33000058  -3--curv---------3--
0x00002710: 595a2000 00000000 009c1800 004fa500 0004fc58  XYZ ----------O-----
0x000028a0: 595a2000 00000000 00348d00 00a02c00 000f9558  XYZ ------4----,----
0x00002a30: 595a2000 00000000 00263100 00102f00 00be9c00  XYZ ------&1---/----
  Properties:
    date:create: 2021-04-09T07:01:47+00:00
    date:modify: 2021-04-09T07:01:47+00:00
    icc:copyright: Copyright 2000 Adobe Systems Incorporated
    icc:description: Adobe RGB (1998)
    minimum-bounding-box:_p: 0,0
    minimum-bounding-box:_q: 1599,0
    minimum-bounding-box:_v: 1598,1056
    minimum-bounding-box:angle: 0
    minimum-bounding-box:area: 1.68854e+06
    minimum-bounding-box:height: 1599
    minimum-bounding-box:unrotate: -0
    minimum-bounding-box:width: 1056
    signature: 272a8b584aacf8e2b7d61d0b8fa608768f9fe5ce1ee34eca2f62dfd8d1885e60
    tiff:alpha: unspecified
    tiff:endian: lsb
    tiff:photometric: RGB
    tiff:rows-per-strip: 208
  Artifacts:
    verbose: true
  Tainted: False
  Filesize: 4.83943MiB
  Number pixels: 1691200
  Pixels per second: 114.282MP
  User time: 0.010u
  Elapsed time: 0:01.014
  Version: ImageMagick 7.0.10-48 Q16 x86_64 2020-12-12 https://imagemagick.org
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.462 1.450u 7.0.10 Cache identify[112]: cache.c/DestroyPixelCache/1057/Cache
  destroy butterfly-1390152.tiff[0]
2021-04-09T07:07:40+00:00 0:01.463 1.450u 7.0.10 Resource identify[112]: resource.c/RelinquishMagickResource/1070/Resource
  Memory: 20294400B/0B/15.3019GiB
```

Comment: Unfortunately i cannot share the file.

Comment: Another thing: I also converted a correct jpg into a tiff file and back, which resulted into the same problem, having only the red-channel in the last result

Comment: It is possible that 7.0.10-48 Imagemagick might have a bug. Can you try another version. It is currently at 7.0.11.-6.  What version of libtiff and libjpeg do you have on both systems. You might upgrade those, if not current.

Comment: Wow.. thank you! using 7.0.10-57 already fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's very hard to help without access to your file! Here are a few suggestions:

- Try running **ImageMagick** with debug switched on to see if you can spot the difference:

  `magick identify -debug all -verbose 100U.tif`
- Try with `exiftool` to see what it makes of your file:

  `exiftool -v -v 100U.tif`

---

If you have **docker**, you can very quickly run up a disposable **Alpine** instance and install **ImageMagick** on it and try like this:

```
docker run --rm -it -v "$(pwd)":/work alpine:latest

/ # apk add --no-cache imagemagick
/ # cd work
/work # magick 100U.TIF 100U.JPG
```

Comment: I just realized, that every tiff to jpg conversion fails. so i took a free image (https://www.freeimages.com/de/photo/butterfly-1390152), converted it into tiff:

```convert butterfly-1390152.jpg butterfly-1390152.tiff``` 

and back:

```convert butterfly-1390152.tiff butterfly-1390152_.jpg```

Results here:

https://ibb.co/ZH1sgmK

https://ibb.co/1qYvkcs

Comment: added this and the debug-output into the main-question

Comment: That looks like a bug. It's highly unlikely that a photo type of image would have so few colours that it could be represented with a palette, and even more unlikely that both your images would have 8-bit red channel and just 1-bit green and blue channels. I suspect a bug or an incompatible version of `libtiff`.

Answer (score 1):

This issue like my issue. I resolve after update imagemagick version

[How to convert a TIFF to a JPG with ImageMagick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67173412/how-to-convert-a-tiff-to-a-jpg-with-imagemagick?noredirect=1#comment118736974_67173412https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67173412/how-to-convert-a-tiff-to-a-jpg-with-imagemagick?noredirect=1#comment118736974_67173412)

Answer (score 0):

As fmw42 pointed out, 7.0.10-48 seems to have a bug (will try to find it in the issue tracker). Updating to 7.0.10-57 fixed the issue.

Comment: could not find a matching bug, but one of these commits could be the "resolution" (correcting/reverting previous changes looks suspicious ;)):
https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/commit/a61f0aeba288473e180da1701ee0bccf9a6dedd0
https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/commit/83c162886f467474c6926a39f34b241dc3016e3c